# Ошибка в описании знака Академик?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, знаки

Недавно получил знак `Академик`, в описании которого сказано:

> Заработать минимум 200 баллов репутации (максимальный результат за день) за один день

Что значит "минимум 200 баллов репутации за один день", если это максимальное количество за один день?

Может я что-то не так понял, поправьте..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это максимальное значение за голоса. Но принятые ответы и награды не учитываются. Так что заработать больше можно. Чтобы получить знак надо заработать 200 или более, так что в *"минимум 200"* ошибки тоже нет. Вроде бы получается, что всё верно.